# Cucumber Puppeteer: Problem passing argument into arrow function

Tags: cucumber, puppeteer, arrow-functions

This is from a world.js in a cucumber puppeteer project.

The first code block causes an error. But if I hard code the selector as in the second code block, there is no error. **How do I pass the argument into the arrow function so I don't have to hard code the selector?** TIA

**Hard coded selector: works**

```js
 async getOriginalForecastDate(selectorTitle, selectorDate, wait = 0) {
      await this.page.waitForSelector(selectorTitle);

      await this.page.waitForSelector(selectorDate);

      const originalDateStr = await this.page.evaluate(selectorDate => {
         let result = document.querySelector('div[class="rollmodel_cal_date"]');
         ////let result = document.querySelector(selectorDate);

         return result.innerText.trim();
      });

      const originalDate = utils.constructDate(originalDateStr);
      return originalDate;
   }
```

**Trying to pass selector as an argument: doesn't work**

```js
 async getOriginalForecastDate(selectorTitle, selectorDate, wait = 0) {
      await this.page.waitForSelector(selectorTitle);

      await this.page.waitForSelector(selectorDate);

      const originalDateStr = await this.page.evaluate(selectorDate => {
           /////let result = document.querySelector('div[class="rollmodel_cal_date"]');
           let result = document.querySelector(selectorDate);

           return result.innerText.trim();
      });

      const originalDate = utils.constructDate(originalDateStr);
      return originalDate;
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass arguments after evaluate arrow function. like this `page.evaluate(pageFunction, ...pageFunction arguments)`. [docs](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v3.3.0/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args).

```
  async getOriginalForecastDate(selectorTitle, selectorDate, wait = 0) {
    await this.page.waitForSelector(selectorTitle);

    await this.page.waitForSelector(selectorDate);

    const originalDateStr = await this.page.evaluate(
      (selectorDate, arg1, arg2) => {
        /////let result = document.querySelector('div[class="rollmodel_cal_date"]');
        let result = document.querySelector(selectorDate);

        return result.innerText.trim();
      },
      selectorDate,
      arg1,
      arg2,
    );

    const originalDate = utils.constructDate(originalDateStr);
    return originalDate;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you Ahmed. I see that you have to add the arguments at the end of the arrow function too.

Comment: You are welcome dear. yes you should add the arguments at the end of the arrow function. to can access it inside arrow function.